# Array.from doesn't work with jasmine

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, jasmine

I'm trying to use Jasmine to test my code, however the code works in the browser, and Array.from() works in node as follows:

```
> t = [1, 2, 3]
[ 1, 2, 3 ]
> Array.from(t)
[ 1, 2, 3 ]
```

Here's the code, which does work in Firefox:

```
var t = [1, 2, 3];
console.log(Array.from(t));
console.log(Array.from(baseObject.childNodes));
```

but when I run my tests I get:

```
 TypeError: undefined is not a function (evaluating 'Array.from(t)') in file:///path/to/my/project/bin/my_module.js (line 154) (1)
```

Comment: We won't know how to make the changes to your existing code base without seeing your original code. Please post [a minimal example of what needs to change](//stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), and fully explain what needs to be modified.

Comment: Also, what runtime are you getting the error in?

Comment: That's all the relevent code.  I create an array and then log a new array created from it to the console using Array.from().  I get the above error in Jasmine but in Firefox I get the expected result:

    Array [ 1, 2, 3 ]
    Array [ #text "
              ", <!--  Comments will be ignored when templating the form out  -->, #text "
             ", <div.input-field.col.m8>, #text "
             ", <div.input-field.col.m1>, #text "
             ", <div.input-field.col.m2>, #text "
            " ]

Comment: Are you running Jasmine in PhantomJS, Node, or what?

Comment: I'm running grunt 1.0.2 in node 6.0.0 which is running jasmine 3.1.0.  This is why I tested Array.from() in node to verify node can run it.

Comment: Do you have PhantomJS anywhere in your dependencies? Also, are you using any polyfills?

Comment: no, my dependencies are:
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-preset-env": "",
    "grunt": "1.0.1",
    "grunt-babel": "^6.0.0",
    "grunt-contrib-clean": "^1.1.0",
    "grunt-contrib-concat": "^1.0.1",
    "grunt-contrib-jasmine": "^1.1.0",
    "jasmine-es6": "",
    "jasmine-jquery": "^2.1.1",
    "jquery": "^3.2.1"
  }

Prior to this question I had babel-preset-latest and jasmine, but changing those 2 have had no effect.

Also the code above is after babel compiled it(although it didn't change anything except adding semi-colons).

Comment: Do you see it anywhere in your `node_modules` directory?

Comment: Yes, grunt-lib-phantomjs is a dependency of grunt-contrib-jasmine.  phantomjs-prebuilt 2.1.16 got installed as a dependency.

Answer (score 2):

`Array.from` was added in the 6th edition (ES2015) of the ECMAScript standard. Make sure you are testing with a sufficiently recent version of ECMAScript.

Comment: I'm aware that Array.from was added in ES2015, but what I don't understand is how node.js has this function, but Jasmine running in node doesn't.  I'm not finding any way to specify the version of JavaScript standard I'm testing with either.

Answer (score 0):

I found from the [comments by Isiah Meadows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50126100/array-from-doesnt-work-with-jasmine?noredirect=1#comment87270904_50126100) that although I'm using node 8.11.1(the version i mentioned in the comments was npm, not node) for grunt which is compatible with ES2017, Jasmine uses PhantomJS which is not fully compatible with ES2015.  As a solution I've done the following:

1. Implimented the [polyfill provided by MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from#Polyfill).
2. After much reading figured out that I need to use [babel-preset-es2015](https://babeljs.io/learn-es2015/) or babel's [env](https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/preset-env/) preset targeting chrome 45 in order to ensure my compiled code is compatible with PhantomJS.